# Count how many words occur in a string

Tags: java, string, count, boolean

everything in this code is well but I am having trouble with the second string. It returns 3 instead of 4 even thought there are four "the"s in the string. I need some help. Thanks!

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    boolean allCorrect = true;

    allCorrect &= testCount("I love to walk to the park", "to", 2);
    allCorrect &= testCount("The theater is in the theater district.", "the", 4);
    allCorrect &= testCount("I am so happy I am getting this right!", " ", 8);
    allCorrect &= testCount("The quick brown fox jumped over the fence", "shoe", 0);
    allCorrect &= testCount("1 is a lonely number but it also always returns 0 when used before the % operator.", "1", 1);
    result(allCorrect, "countHowManyinString");
}

public class stringActivty {
    public static int countHowManyinString(String fullString, String partString)
    {
        int count = 0;
        int index = 0;
        while ((index = fullString.indexOf(partString, index)) != -1) {
            count++;
            index += partString.length();
        }
        return count;
    }
    public static boolean testCount(String strA, String strB, int answer)
    {
        int result = countHowManyinString(strA, strB);

        if (result == answer) {
            System.out.println("CORRECT! There are " + answer + " instances of \"" + strB + "\" in \"" + strA + "\"");
            return true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Keep trying! There are " + answer + " instances of \"" + strB + "\" in \"" + strA + "\" but your method returned " + result);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Uppercase/lowercase checking. Convert pattern and string to the same case before counting.

Comment: The problem is with case sensitive 'The'.  Try using "while ((index = fullString.toLowerCase().indexOf(partString.toLowerCase(), index)) != -1) {"

Answer (score 1):

It could be because you are looking for "the" with small letters, but the first "The" has capital T.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first "The" as a "T" in uppercase. If you don't want to be case sensitive you have to convert the string to lowercase:

```
public static int countHowManyinString(String fullString, String     partString)
{
    fullString = fullString.toLowerCase()
    int count = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while ((index = fullString.indexOf(partString, index)) != -1) {
        count++;
        index += partString.length();
    }
    return count;
}
```